# No type or protocol named 'CLLocationManagerDelegate' in ProjectName-Swift.h

Tags: objective-c, swift, cllocationmanager

My project comprises both ObjC and Swift files. I have created a swift file with API to get the user's current location and address(using reverse geocoding). And I'm calling this API from my objC file. Whenever I build my code, am getting the error

> "No type or protocol named 'CLLocationManagerDelegate'" in my
>   ProjectName-Swift.h

The error in the file is:

> @interface GeoLocatorInterface : NSObject
>   <**CLLocationManagerDelegate**>

When I delete this `CLLocationManagerDelegate` from the above line, my project builds fine. Though I delete `CLLocationManagerDelegate`, when I build for next time, this is automatically getting created and throwing me the same error.

Kindly help me in resolving this issue at the earliest.

TIA.

Comment: Try importing CoreLocation.

Comment: I have imported CoreLocation in my Swift file and also in Project's bridging header.h.
Even then facing the same issue.
Kindly read my question. After few compilation only, I'm getting the error.